# Rewrite your program and ask either user want to continue the calculation (Yes/No) in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

i have already complete the MUL calculation but the real problem is i need to rewrite the program and do this task " Rewrite your program and ask either user want to continue the
calculation (Yes/No). If Yes, user can have a selection either perform MUL or DIV. If No, print “Thank you” and exit the program." Can someone show me the code how to do this ?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
str1 BYTE "Please enter a multiplicand (n) <1...9>: ",0
str2 BYTE "Please enter a multiplier (m) <1...9>: ",0
str3 BYTE "Multiplication of: ",0
str4 BYTE "The product is: ",0
str5 BYTE " x ",0
str6 BYTE "Do you want to continue ? [Yes/No] : "
multiplicand dword ?
multiplier dword ?
product dword 0
answer dword ?

.code 

main PROC

call clrscr ; clear the console and locates the cursor at the upperleft corner.

mov edx, offset str1 ; move the address of str1 to edx
call WriteString ; display the string "str1"
call ReadDec ; read a 32bit unsigned number input from user
mov multiplicand, eax ; move the input from user into "multiplicand"

mov edx, offset str2 ; move the address of str2 to edx
call WriteString ; display the string "str1"
call ReadDec ; read a 32bit unsigned number input from user
mov multiplier, eax ; move the input from user into "multiplier"

call crlf ; add newline
mov edx, offset str3 ; move the address of str3 to edx
call WriteString ; display the string "str3"

mov eax, multiplicand ; move multiplicand into eax
call WriteDec ;  display the value eax from multiplicand
mov edx, offset str5 ; move the address of str5 to edx
call WriteString ; display str5

mov eax, multiplier ; move multiplier into ebx
call WriteDec ; display value eax from multiplier

mul multiplicand ; eax*multiplicand value
mov product, eax ; mov eax value into product

call crlf
mov edx, offset str4
call crlf
call WriteString ; display the string of str4
call WriteDec
call crlf

mov edx, offset str6
call crlf
call WriteString
call ReadString



exit 

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Look up `cmp` and conditional jumps in your textbook.

Comment: basically i don't have any textbook to refer , that's why i ask here. Because in my class i'm still not learning about how to do conditional jump.

Comment: Conditional jumps are really the only way to accomplish an "if".  And asking on this site is not really a good way to be taught something for the first time.  Look around for other tutorials, books, etc.  There are some references at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Then come back and ask when you have a more specific question and some background in the area.